Create an environment that encapsulates gather* environment
I want to create environment that encapsulates gather* environment. The code I wish worked is the following and I believe my intent is made very clear with it. I'd like it to be possible to make an environment which fully does the same thing as gather*, but is wrapped inside my own environment where I might have some other functions added.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{mygather}
{\begin{gather*}}
{\end{gather*}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mygather}
        a^n + b^n = c^n
    \end{mygather}
\end{document}

The closest thing that I got working is with \gather and \endgather macros but I don't know how to access the starred version of them. Here is the working code but I want the equations not to be numbered.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{mygather}
{\gather}
{\endgather}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mygather}
        a^n + b^n = c^n
    \end{mygather}
\end{document}


This feels like an XY problem.  What are these "other functions" that you might want in with gather*?  There are ways to access \gather* and \endgather*, or to access \gather and \endgather but without numbering.  But hooks sound like they might be what you want.  But it's hard to tell without knowing what you actually want to do.

The definition given in amsmath is
\newenvironment{gather*}{%
  \start@gather\st@rredtrue
}{%
  \endgather
}

so you can just copy it and add whatever you are planning. This avoids double scanning of the whole content as in the other answers.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}% twocolumn for smaller snapshot

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mygather}{%
   \start@gather\st@rredtrue
   % whatever you are planning comes probably here
  }{%
   \endgather
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some meaningless text some meaningless text some
meaningless text some meaningless text
\begin{mygather}
  a^n + b^n = c^n \\
  x^n - y^n = z^n
\end{mygather}
Some meaningless text some meaningless text some
meaningless text some meaningless text

\end{document}


Alternatively you could use
\newenvironment{mygather}{\csname gather*\endcsname}{\endgather}


No need of packages (except amsmath, of course): the contents is absorbed because of the b argument type and is available as #1.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mygather}{b}{%
  \begin{gather*}
  #1
  \end{gather*}%
}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

Some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text
\begin{mygather}
  a^n + b^n = c^n \\
  x^n - y^n = z^n
\end{mygather}
some text some text some text some text some text some text
some text some text some text some text some text some text

\end{document}


What you want to “apply” is unknown, though.

You can use the environ package
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewEnviron{mygather}{%
    \begin{gather*}
        \BODY
    \end{gather*}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mygather}
        a^n + b^n = c^n
    \end{mygather}
\end{document}


You can also use \[...\] + gathered (and not use the environ package)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{mygather}{\[\gathered}{\endgathered\]}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mygather}
        a^n + b^n = c^n
    \end{mygather}
\end{document}

